# Como juntar botão editar/novo?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update, sql-insert

Gostaria que, caso já exista o `$nome` cadastrado na tabela, ele dê um update e caso não exista, ele dê um insert. Não entendo qual o problema no meu código.

```
$dbconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)or die("Failed to connect to database:" . mysqli_error($dbconn));
if (isset($_POST['botao_editar']))
{

$Nome = trim($_POST['txtNome']); 
$NIF = trim($_POST['txtNif']); 
$bday = trim($_POST['txtnascimento']); 
$email = trim($_POST['txtEmail']); 
$telemovel = trim($_POST['txtTelemovel']); 
$morada = trim($_POST['txtMorada']); 
$codigo = trim($_POST['txtCodigo']); 
$localidade = trim($_POST['txtLocalidade']); 
$especialidade = trim($_POST['txtEspecialidade']); 
$observacao = trim($_POST['txtObservacao']); 
$cbnome= trim($_POST['cbMedicos']);

 $query = "UPDATE Medicos SET nome= '".$Nome."', NIF='".$nif."', data_nascimento='".$bday."', email='".$email."', telemovel='".$telemovel."', morada='".$morada."', codigo_postal= '".$codigo."', Localidade= '".$localidade."', especialidade= '".$especialidade."', observacoes= '".$observacao."' WHERE nome = '$cbnome'";  
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($data);

    if ($result == 0) 
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO Medicos (nome, NIF, telemovel, data_nascimento, email, morada , observacoes, codigo_postal, especialidade, Localidade )  VALUES ('".$Nome."', '".$nif."', '".$telemovel."', '".$bday."', '".$email."', '".$morada."', '".$observacao."', '".$codigo."', '".$especialidade."', '".$localidade."')";

    $data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);

    echo  "<br>Dados do pacientes gravados com sucesso <br>";
}
        else
        {
                echo "<br> O novo paciente foi inserido com sucesso <br>";
            }

else
    {

        echo  "<br>Falhou a inserir os dados <br>";
        ?>

    <?php
    }
    mysqli_close($dbcon);
    ?>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Francisco não tenho nenhum exemplo, mas posso tentar explicar melhor... Eu preencho os campos e depois carrego no botão, quando isso acontece ele faz um update no caso de existir um nome =cbnome, caso não existe é porque é uma nova entrada e por isso faz o insert.

Comment: Entendi o que você quer, mas no seu código, o que não está funcionando? O update? O insert? Os 2?

Comment: acho q não é necessário vc fazer um update, e se o retorno for 0, dar um insert... tem outras formas de fazer isso rsrs

Comment: @Francisco Creio que as querys estejam corretas, acho que o problema está no seguimento do código...  Só não consigo descobrir em quê, se é algum parênteses ou se falta alguma linha de código...

Comment: Caso alguma resposta tenha lhe ajudado, não se esqueça de marcar como correta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o campo `$name` nesse insert deveria ser `$Nome`.

E estava faltando um mysqliquery logo após o Insert:

```
    if ($result == 0) 
    {
      $query = "INSERT INTO Medicos (nome, NIF, telemovel, 

      data_nascimento, email, morada , observacoes, codigo_postal,

      especialidade, Localidade ) 

      VALUES ('".$name."', '".$nif."','".$telemovel."', '".$bday."',

              '".$email."', '".$morada."', '".$observacoes."', 

              '".$codigo_postal."', '".$especialidade."', '".$localidade."')";

        $data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);

        echo  "<br>Dados do pacientes gravados com sucesso <br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo fazer a verificação já dentro do SQL, com o `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Medicos (nome, NIF, telemovel, 
      data_nascimento, email, morada , observacoes, codigo_postal,
      especialidade, Localidade ) 
      VALUES ('".$name."', '".$nif."','".$telemovel."', '".$bday."',
              '".$email."', '".$morada."', '".$observacoes."', 
              '".$codigo_postal."', '".$especialidade."', '".$localidade."')";
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
              nome= '".$Nome."', NIF='".$nif."', data_nascimento='".$bday."',
              email='".$email."', telemovel='".$telemovel."',
              morada='".$morada."', codigo_postal= '".$codigo."',
              Localidade= '".$localidade."', especialidade= '".$especialidade."',
              observacoes= '".$observacao."'";
```

Não sei se ta certinho, qualquer duvida você pode olhar na [documentação original](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).